# How to snowpark UDF function in snowpark dataframe using python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf

import numpy as np
import math

@udf(packages=["numpy"])

def quantile_udf(x: float) -> float:

  return np.quantile(x,0.95)

@udf(packages=["numpy"])

def mean_udf(x: float) -> float:

  return np.mean(x)

tf = df_operation.groupBy('STORE_ID').function(mean_udf("REG_SLS_U"))

tf is <function snowflake.snowpark.relational_grouped_dataframe.RelationalGroupedDataFrame.function.<locals>.<lambda>(*cols)>
```

How to call the UDF function in a dataframe and print the data in the tf. The same code is working with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try tf.show()? It prints a small number of rows of your data. Or tf.collect() which returns all the rows without printing.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.show.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.collect.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems you would like to do something like this

```
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf

import numpy as np
import math

@udf(packages=["numpy"])
def mean_udf(x: float) -> float:
  return np.mean(x)

df_groupby = df_operation.groupBy('STORE_ID')
tf = df_groupby.agg(mean_udf("REG_SLS_U").as_("tf"))
tf is <snowflake.snowpark.dataframe.DataFrame at 0x131c1eb20>
```

Checkout some examples [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/ko/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.udf.UDFRegistration.html#snowflake.snowpark.udf.UDFRegistration)

Comment: getting error "'RelationalGroupedDataFrame' object has no attribute 'select'"

Comment: @SaeedRahman could you try `df_groupby.agg` instead of `df_groupby.select`

Comment: I was able to do this with UDTF rather than UDF